# Locally invoke a AWS Lambda function and pass `event` and `context`

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have this function -

```
export const voidTransaction = async function (
  event: ApiEvent,
  context: ApiContext,
): Promise<ApiResponse> {
  return lambdaWrapper(async () => {
    const body = await start<NayaxVoidRequestBody>(event, context, 'Void-Request');
    return {
      body: await voidNayaxTransaction(
        event.pathParameters.transactionId,
        body.reasonText,
        body.reasonCode,
      ),
    };
  });
};
```

I need to call this function from another function and pass in the event and context, how do I pass in the arguments as when I specify an event like so -

```
const voidResponse = await voidTransaction(pathParameters: {
        transactionId: transaction.id,
      }, context);
```

it throws me an error saying -

`Argument of type '{ pathParameters: { transactionId: any; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'APIGatewayProxyEvent'`

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a JSON object:

```
pathParameters: {
        transactionId: transaction.id,
      }
```

You need to wrap it in `{ }` brackets to make it a JSON object:

```
const voidResponse = await voidTransaction({pathParameters: {
        transactionId: transaction.id,
      }}, context);
```